# adding Text to SVG document in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I'm trying to add a text element to the `<g>` element in a SVG document using javascript
my code looks like this

```
function addText(x,y,val){
    var newtxt = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "text");
    $newtxt = $(newtxt);
    $newtxt.attr('x',x);
    $newtxt.attr('y',y);
    $newtxt.attr('font-size','100');
    $newtxt.val(val);
    $newtxt.appendTo($('g'));
}
```

but when I run it the text is not shown.
the element is added to the `<g>` element, but the value is not set..
any ideas how to solve this??

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I think you need to create a text node to hold the string and append that to the SVG text element.

```
var svgNS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
var newText = document.createElementNS(svgNS,"text");
newText.setAttributeNS(null,"x",x);     
newText.setAttributeNS(null,"y",y); 
newText.setAttributeNS(null,"font-size","100");

var textNode = document.createTextNode(val);
newText.appendChild(textNode);
document.getElementById("g").appendChild(newText);
```

There's a working example at http://old.carto.net/papers/svg/manipulating_svg_with_dom_ecmascript/.

Comment: I've verified that this is correct. (Using createTextNode.) Should be marked as the answer.

Comment: Bill can you update the link it directs to 404 page.

Answer (score 6):

```
var txt = document.createElementNS(svgNS, 'text');
txt.setAttributeNS(null, 'x', x);
txt.setAttributeNS(null, 'y', y);
txt.setAttributeNS(null,'font-size','100');
txt.innerHTML = val;
document.getElementById("g").appendChild(txt);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: Please explain some information on how this works Casey and why we need NS and the null values.

Comment: The trick is the property `innerHTML`. Interestingly, this node does not have `innerText`

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, if you want to update the text value dynamically then you could use `textContent` property.

```
const textNS = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg","text");
const textNode = document.createTextNode("Old Value");
textNS.appendChild(textNode);
document.body.appendChild(textNS);

textNS.textContent = "New Value";
```

Comment: Actually, there is no need to explicitly create a text node. It works just fine to use textContent to set the text of the SVG `text` element right away after it has been created. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent – “Setting textContent on a node removes all of the node's children and replaces them with a single text node with the given string value.”