# HTML not updating when SVG <text> modified

Tags: javascript, html, svg

EDIT: The issue is not as it turns out in the posted code, although I'm not sure if the question is still useful.

Before I state my quandary, let me first explain that I'm building a small online app for personal use. I know for a fact that everyone who's going to use it uses Chrome, so there's no need to go out of my way to make sure it's supported by IE. Here goes:

I have a part of an SVG whose HTML goes roughly like this:

```
<g class="clue">
    <g class="cypher">
        <circle cy="20" class="roundButton></circle>
        <text x="5" y="22" transform="rotate(60 0,20)">yo!</text>
    </g>
</g>
```

Obviously abbreviated for clarity. I have a need to modify the text to say "orange hippopotamus" rather then "yo!", and so I've made this function to get the `<text>` element, creating one if needed:

```
function getOrCreateLabel(Clue,Cypher){
    var test=Cypher.getElementsByTagName("text");
    if(test.length>0)
        return test[0]; //This works 'cuz each cypher only has 1 <text> element.
    label=document.createElement("text");
    label.setAttribute("x",5);
    label.setAttribute("y",22);
    label.setAttribute("transform","rotate(60 0,20)");
    Cypher.appendChild(label);
    return label;
}
```

I figured that'd allow me to simply write `getOrCreateLabel(Clue,Cypher).innerHTML="orange hippopotamus";` having previously assigned Clue and Cypher to the appropriate elements, but alas it hasn't turned out that way...

Upon testing it, I've found that the changes *are* made to the text element, but not to the actual HTML.

I've tried *everything* I can think of:

- setting the surrounding HTML equal to itself (which I had previously found was necessary to get Chrome to refresh the image)- no dice; the problem is that the HTML isn't getting updated, rather than the image not being updated.
- removing and re-adding the text element- Funnily enough, while I could get the element to disappear from the list of children of the Cypher, I couldn't get the element to vanish from the Cypher innerHTML.
- removing the text element via modifying the innerHTML of the containing Cypher- Yes, I did indeed resort to manually parsing the innerHTML and removing the bit about the text element. Unfortunately, while this worked as verified by going to the console and requesting the innerHTML in question, the page HTML remained unchanged.
- just to see what would happen, I tried to simply call remove() the obtained text element, but there was absolutely no result.

Any help would be very much appreciated; I'm not much of a fan of javascript at the best of times, let alone when I've spent the better part of a day wrestling with something like this.

Comment: If this question isn't going to help anyone else (because the problem isn't in the posted code) then it's probably best deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it turns out the problem wasn't with the code I posted, but rather was that I was trying to pass a parameter to the function by reference, not remembering that that kind of thing is a no-go in js. Lesson learned! Thank you so much for your help and quick replies, sin tribu.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused by your question as I don't know what HTML you are referring to. Are you setting innerHTML to your label? Also, if you are trying to change the text element from 'yo' -> 'orange hippo' how is it going to change when you return if there is an existing element.

If you are trying to remove 'yo' and replace with 'orange hippo' you can do this taken from [adding Text to SVG document in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9281199/adding-text-to-svg-document-in-javascript)

```
function getOrCreateLabel(Clue,Cypher){
    // removed so yo is replaced with orange hippo
    //var test=Cypher.getElementsByTagName("text");
    //if(test.length>0)
    //    return test[0]; //This works 'cuz each cypher only has 1 <text> element.

    // use createElementNS function instead of createElement
    //label=document.createElement("text"); 
    var label = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "text")


    label.setAttribute( "x",5);
    label.setAttribute( "y",22);
    label.setAttribute( "transform","rotate(60 0,20)");

    //create a text node before appending
    let textNode = document.createTextNode("orange hypopotamus");

    //append text node to label
    label.appendChild( textNode )

    // apend label to cypher
    Cypher.appendChild(label);

    return label;
}
```

I hope I didn't misunderstand your question.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to replace "Yo!" with "hippo", and the trouble I'm having is that the HTML printed in Chrome's developer tools pane under "elements" isn't changing at all, although I can see the desired changes are having an effect at some level if I go to the console to verify the different values.

Comment: Did you try using ```document.getCreateElementNS``` instead of ```document.createElement()``` The label shows up fine form if I set eighter innerHTML on label  or add a textNode to it. But it doesn't render 'hippo' if I use ```document.createElement()```

Comment: I changed to document.getCreateElementNS, but after solving the issue changed it back as an experiment, and found it made no difference. It's interesting that for you it did, though; I should bear that in mind.

Comment: Glad you figured it out. It seems like changing the text of a node would be easy but if you're a novice/ hobbyist javascript programmer like myself you know nothing is easy with javascript, but at least everything is possible. Good luck on your app!